# SQLServer 2008 UPSERT merge without repeating the values

Tags: sql-server

I have created a pseudo UPSERT statement which works, however due to the fact that the data to insert or update might be quite large, in order to reduce network bandwidth, I would like to only define the data to be updated or inserted once.

For brevity, in my example I have only incuded 2 fields and both have very short data length, but in the real system there may be dozens of fields, and some of them may be very long.

```
MERGE PART AS T 
USING (SELECT ID) AS S 
ON(S.ID = T.ID) 
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET ID='ABCD-000',DESCRIPTION='NEW DESCRIPTION' 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES('ABCD-000','NEW DESCRIPTION');
```

In this example, the ID is unique, if therecord exists then it should be updated, if it does not exist then a new record should be inserted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
MERGE PART AS T 
USING (
    SELECT
        'ABCD-000' as ID,
        'NEW DESCRIPTION' NewDescription
    ) AS S
ON (S.ID = T.ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET T.DESCRIPTION=S.NewDescription
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (ID,DESCRIPTION) VALUES(S.ID, S.NewDescription);
```

Also, no need to do `SET ID='ABCD-000'` on `WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE`, because of your mathcing condition is `S.ID = T.ID` already.

Comment: This works for me if the record exists (update), but does not appear to work if it is an insert. I am guessing that is because if the record does not exist then S will be null and there's no data to insert the record with ?

Comment: @crankshaft, I think I understand. So `SELECT * FROM PART WHERE ID = 'ABCD-000'` should select exactly one record? And if it exists you update description, and if not you insert. In this case see answer updated. Or do you expect multiple rows for `ID = 'ABCD-000'?

Comment: In this example the ID is unique, in reality there are a LOT more fields than just these 2. If the record exists, then the fields should be updated, if the record does not exist then a new record should be inserted.

Comment: @crankshaft, updated from constants or do you need other columns to update data from?

Comment: I believe that in your example, if the PART ID A8000 does not exist, the the select will return null and there is therefore no S.ID or S.DESCRIPTION to pass to the insert stament,

Comment: @crankshaft, after `USING` is changed to `(SELECT 'ABCD-000' as ID, 'NEW DESCRIPTION' NewDescription) AS S` select will always return single row, i.e. it should be fine for upsert.